# Conditionally log based on level

Tags: android, logging

Is there a way to generate log output based on a user-settable log level?  For example, if the user chooses to log at "verbose", then all messages will be written to the log.  Alternatively if the user chooses to log at "warn", then only messages of level "warn" and higher will be written to the log.

Notice I'm not asking how to filter using logcat to get "verbose" or "warn" or whatever messages.  Instead, I want to filter what goes *into* the log.

Obviously, I can write my own wrappers that go around log.d(), etc.  Just wondering if I overlooked something like this.

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer your question, but [logback-android](http://tony19.github.io/logback-android) could be configured to do what you're asking for.

Answer (score 2):

Yep,

**public static String setProperty (String name, String value)** (  java.lang.System)

**public static boolean isLoggable (String tag, int level)** (  android.util.Log)

Checks to see whether or not a log for the specified tag is loggable at the specified level. **The default level of any tag is set to INFO. This means that any level above and including INFO will be logged.** Before you make any calls to a logging method you should check to see if your tag should be logged. **You can change the default level by setting a system property: 'setprop log.tag. ' Where level is either VERBOSE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, ASSERT, or SUPPRESS. SUPPRESS will turn off all logging for your tag**. You can also create a local.prop file that with the following in it: 'log.tag.=' and place that in /data/local.prop.

Comment: Thanks, that's half of what I was looking for.  It still requires the wrapper though.